# Missing values in nested ifelse statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement

At some point in time, I encountered this problem...and solved it. However, as it is a recurring problem and I've now forgotten the solution, hopefully this question will offer clarification to others as well as me :)

I am creating a variable that is based answers to several questions. Each question can have three values: 1, 2, or NA. 1's and 2's are mutually exclusive for each observation.

I simply want to create a variable that is a composite of the choice coded with "1" for each person, and give it a value based on that code.

So let's say I have this `df`:

```
ID   var1    var2   var3   var4
1    1       2      NA     NA
2    NA      NA     2      1
3    2       1      NA     NA
4    2       NA     1      NA
```

I then try to recode based on the following statement:

```
df$var <- 
    ifelse(
        as.numeric(df$var1) == 1,
        "Gut instinct",
        ifelse(
            as.numeric(df$var2) == 1,
            "Data",
            ifelse(
                as.numeric(df$var3) == 1,
                "Science",
                ifelse(
                    as.numeric(df$var4) == 1,
                    "Philosophy",
                    NA
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

However, this code only PARTIALLY codes based on the "ifelse".  For example, `df$var` might have  observation of 'Gut instinct' and 'Philosophy', but the codings for when `var2` and `var3==1` are still NA.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: Perhaps you should show your expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative that will be quicker than `apply` (using @MrFlick's data):

```
vals <- c("Gut", "Data", "Science", "Phil")
intm <- dd[-1]==1 & !is.na(dd[-1])
dd$resp <- NA
dd$resp[row(intm)[intm]] <- vals[col(intm)[intm]]
```

How much quicker? On 1 million rows:

```
#row/col assignment
user  system elapsed 
0.99    0.02    1.02 

#apply
 user  system elapsed 
11.98    0.04   12.30
```

And giving the same results when tried on identical datasets:

```
identical(flick$resp,latemail$resp)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I didn't even know about the `row` and `col` functions before

Comment: I'm really glad I deleted my answer now. :) It would have been 50 times slower.  Haha.

Comment: Although, to be fair, i doubt this is a function that really needs to be optimized for speed. As they say, premature optimization is the root of all evil. But still, nice to know all the options. Best to pick one that makes most sense to the code maintainer.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `ifelse` (and `==`) has special behavior for `NA`. Specifically, R doesn't want to tell you that `NA` is different from `1` (or anything else), because often `NA` is used to represent a value that *could* be anything, maybe even `1`.

```
> 1 == NA
[1] NA

> ifelse(NA == 1, "yes", "no")
[1] NA
```

With your code, if an `NA` occurs before a `1` (like for `ID` 2), then that `ifelse` statement will just return `NA`, and the nested `FALSE` `ifelse` will never be called.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do with without the nested ifelse statements

```
#your data
dd<-data.frame(ID = 1:4, 
    var1 = c(1, NA, 2, 2), 
    var2 = c(2, NA, 1, NA), 
    var3 = c(NA, 2, NA, 2), 
    var4 = c(NA, 1, NA, NA)
)

resp <- c("Gut","Data","Sci","Phil")[apply(dd[,-1]==1,1,function(x) which(x)[1])]
cbind(dd, resp)
```

I use `apply` to scan across the rows to find the first 1 and use that index to subset the response values. Using `which` helps to deal with the `NA` values.

Comment: (+1) very nice use of vectorization.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question it is due to the NAs in your data. This should sort your problem out

```
df <- data.frame( ID=1:4, var1= c(1, NA, 2, 2), var2= c(2, NA, 1, NA),
var3=c(NA,2,NA,2), var4=c(NA, 1, NA, NA))

df$var<-ifelse(as.numeric(df$var1)==1&!is.na(df$var1),"Gut instinct", 
           ifelse(as.numeric(df$var2)==1&!is.na(df$var2),"Data",
                  ifelse(as.numeric(df$var3)==1&!is.na(df$var3),"Science",
                      ifelse(as.numeric(df$var4)==1&!is.na(df$var4),"Philosophy",NA))))
```

However, I would find it easier to reshape the data into a 'matrix' rather than a table and do it using a vector.

```
data <- df
library(reshape2)
long <- melt(data, id.vars="ID")
long
```

This would give you a matrix. Convert the var titles to something more meaningful.

```
library(stringr)
long$variable <- str_replace(long$variable, "var1", "Gut Instinct")
long$variable <- str_replace(long$variable, "var2", "Data")
long$variable <- str_replace(long$variable, "var3", "Science")
long$variable <- str_replace(long$variable, "var4", "Philosophy")
```

And now you can decide what to do based on each result

```
long$var <- ifelse(long$value==1, long$variable, NA)
```

and convert it back to something like the  original if you want it that way

```
reshape(data=long, timevar="ID",idvar=c("var", "variable"), v.names = "value", direction="wide")
```

HTH